# Jacoco: Add coverage for failed test cases

Tags: java, ant, jacoco

I am using Jacoco with Ant on a Java project which has a combination of unit tests as well as integration tests. We also have tests for REST APIs. In case there is a failure in any of the test cases, the entire class is not getting covered as part of Jacoco code coverage. Is there any configuration that I need to set to ensure that at least a part of code that has been executed as part of tests is covered? Here is my jacoco report XML

```
    <jacoco:report>    
     <structure name="Jacoco Report">
      <classfiles>
        <fileset dir="${build.classes.dir}">
          <exclude name="ut/**"/>
          <exclude name="com/**/test/**"/>
        </fileset>
      </classfiles>
      <sourcefiles>
      <fileset dir="${build.source.dir}">
        <exclude name="ut/**"/>
        <exclude name="com/**/test/**"/>
      </fileset>
    </sourcefiles>
  </structure>
   <!-- to produce reports in different formats. -->
   <html destdir="${build.root.dir}/jacoco"/>
   <csv destfile="${build.root.dir}/jacoco/report.csv"/>
   <xml destfile="${build.root.dir}/jacoco/report.xml"/>
  </jacoco:report>
```